# AWS Rekognition Service: Improve facial recognition accuracy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm finding the right way to use AWS Rekognition service.

My problem is **How to verify a person image on multi collections**, I'm reading [Build Your Own Face Recognition Service Using Amazon Rekognition | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-your-own-face-recognition-service-using-amazon-rekognition/) from Amazon but cannot find the implementation document for it. My point is **Face verification** title.

**Update 1**:

My target is: Using AWS Rekognition to get person's info by their face.

My problem is: How to make AWS Rekognition improves its accuracy when recognizing a face.

What I tried:

1. Upload multi captured portraits of a person with same *ExternalImageID* but I'm not sure it works or not.
2. Finding a way to create **Collection** for each person, then upload person's portraits to their **Collection** but I don't how to search a face through multiple **Collections**.
3. I'm trying use S3 for storage people's images then using Lambda function to do something that I've not got yet.

**Update 2**:

1. **What is your input material:** Input materials are some people's portrait photo with ExternalImageID is their name (eg: my portrait photo will have ExternalImageID is "Long").
2. **What are you trying to do:** I'm trying to get ExternalImageID when I send a portrait photo of a registered person. (eg: with my other portrait photo, AWS has to response ExternalImageID is "Long").
3. **Do you have it working, but it is not recognizing some people?** Yes, it's work but sometimes it cannot recognize exactly people.
4. **Please tell us your use-case / scenario and what you are trying to accomplish:**

   - Create an AWS Rekognition collection with sample name (eg facetest).
   - Register some people with their name is ExternalImageID.
   - Submit an image to AWS Rekognition API to get ExternalImageID - his name.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by "verify a person image on multi collections"? What have you tried and what difficulties are you experiencing? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I've updated my post, please take a look at it!

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do. What is your input material (eg still pictures? Of who)? What are you trying to do (eg identify a person in a picture, or obtain information about a person in a picture, such as age, smiling, gender)? What do you mean by "improve its accuracy"? Do you have it working, but it is not recognizing some people? Please tell us your use-case / scenario and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion, I've updated more data that based on your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so basically you have it working but it doesn't always recognise the person. I'll assume it does not even list the person in the response, even with a low percentage.

I would recommend **adding multiple images of the same person to the Face Collection**, specifying the same `ExternalImageId` for each image. (Use one Face Collection with all people in it, including multiple images of the same person.)

Please note that *"If you provide the same image, specify the same collection, and use the same external ID in the IndexFaces operation, Amazon Rekognition doesn't save duplicate face metadata."* However, adding *different* images with the same `ExternalImageId` should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! And one more thing I need a professional's help like you is: Could you provide some documents for Rekognition with Live Video Streaming?

Comment: I recommend watching presentations from the [AWS re:Invent conference](http://aws-reinvent-audio.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2017/2017.html). There is an [Intro to Rekognition Video](https://youtu.be/LF0cMXDbmDs) session.

Comment: My team has been researching AWS's document for a few days but we still cannot submit data stream from iphone's front camera to Kinesis stream for using AWS Rekognition Live Video Stream.
We're follow this document: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/recognize-faces-in-a-video-stream.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/recognize-faces-in-a-video-stream.html)
I'm sorry if I make you confuse again @@

Comment: Could you please provide some iOS sample with AWS Rekognition Video Stream? Thank you so much!

Comment: I haven't played with real-time streaming Rekognition Video. However, I have played with recognising faces in video files stored in Amazon S3: [Automated video editing with YOU as the star! | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automated-video-editing-with-you-as-the-star/)